# Eigenvectors of non-singular matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that for an $N\times N$ Hermitian matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, there exist $N$ eigenvectors that are linearly independent and form a complete, orthonormal basis for the space $\mathbb{C}^N$.

Is it possible to find a non-singular matrix where its eigenvectors can not form a complete orthonormal basis? (This means we can't find $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors for this non-singular matrix). Is this situation possible? If so, what are the properties required in the matrix to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the famous example:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$
It has only one eigenvector: $(1,0)$.

(Remark: most of the time, if you want to know if a property holds for all matrices, this is a good one to check first when looking for counterexamples.)

Comment: So, symmetry is the real key to having linearly independent eigenvectors?